# Is there any way I can optimize the multi variate function using vector as an input in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have one quick question. This is just a sample code I just wrote.

```
clear;
A = [1;2];
obj         = @(Vs,Vx) -Vs.^2 - A.*Vx.^2;
```

I want to solve the above problem.

I know I can do something like this

```
clear
a = 1:1:2;
f = @(x) (x-a).^2;
x1 = arrayfun( @(v) fminsearch(@(x) x(1)^2 + v*x(2)^2, [0;0]), a, 'UniformOutput', false);
x1 = [x1{:}]
```

But I want to use a vector itself as an input.

Is there any way I can solve such problem?

Comment: Why do you want to use a vector itself?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. In particular, your obj function above does not return a scalar value. Can you write some pseudo code to explain what you would like to do and what the result would be?